# Notepad++ color printing or alternatives

Tags: printing, notepad++

I'm trying to print some source code using notepad++ and I'm hoping to be able to keep keyword highlighting and styling on some lines (background color ) I thought as long as I have WYSIWYG selected on the printing preferences i would get just that..what I see. 
But it prints in black and white. any idea why?

If it's not possible for npp to do it, any alternatives?

Comment: If anyone stumbles on this thread trying to figure out how to disable background color printing in Notepad++, see this article:  http://webunder.com.au/weblog/how-to-save-ink-with-notepad-while-using-port-ruby-blue-theme/

I definitely wasted a whole toner cartridge this morning on my dark-gray background.

Comment: @Brad: I usually just switch to another color theme with white as the background. That's what I did when printing my assignments' source code. And I'm sorry to hear about your wasted toner :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about printer settings

Comment: @Brad that link is broken, unfortunately. Hoping for a better solution than what BoltClock says.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notepad++ does support color printing. You'll probably want to check your printer settings and/or have your color ink cartridge replaced.

Comment: yeah i think you are right, my printer settings are all messed up

Answer (score 2):

I just printed some syntax highlighted XML from [Programmer's Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Express (2008, at least) prints text colored.